# Windows Service Based Software to Run Script Everytime a file arrives

Tags: windows, scripting, automation, files

Does anyone know of a tool were that is service based which I would be able to run a script every time a file arrives in a directory? I would write the script all I want is the tool to be a service based application.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a service using the .NET class [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx). More information is available at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517460/is-there-anything-like-inotify-on-windows).

Comment: and or just create a simple wmi query using the ISA event notification process. still trying to find a good easy example will post when I find one.

Comment: @tony roth: Interesting.  I'm curious to see your example.

Answer (score 0):

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
    strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
    ("Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent Within 5 Where " _
    & "Targetinstance Isa 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and " _
    & "TargetInstance.GroupComponent= " _
    & "'Win32_Directory.Name=""c:\\\\scripts""'")

Do
    Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
    Wscript.Echo objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.PartComponent
Loop
```